# Xamarin Architecture Projects or Namespaces

Tags: xamarin, architecture

I am developing an app for iOS, Android and Windows phone with Xamarin, and I have a doubt about the architecture. From their website:

[image]

And from the example solution they provide:

[link to git source](https://github.com/xamarin/mobile-samples/tree/master/TaskyPortable)

They put the Business Layer, the Data Access Layer and the Data Layer in the same project.

But after this, when they explain the architecture:

Encapsulation: [...] This means that the UI code (for example) should only be responsible for displaying screens and accepting user-input; and never interacting with the database directly. [...]

and:

[...]Separating code into layers make applications easier to understand, test and maintain. It is recommended that the code in each layer be physically separate (**either in directories or even separate projects for very large applications**) as well as logically separate (using namespaces).[...]
(Emphasis mine)

Would not it be better if they were on separate projects? I mean, if all it's in the same project, and I reference this project in the UI Layer, then I can acces The Business Layer, and the Data Layer directly, I do not know if this is correct.

The questions are:

It's acceptable (and accepted), to separate the layers with directories?

It's better (or most accepted) to separate the layers with directories and namespaces, or with projects?

Comment: All answers so far helped me to see that is not always necesary to separate the layers in projects. It is a pitty that I can only accept one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would not it be better if they were on separate projects? I mean, if
>   all it's in the same project, and I reference this project in the UI
>   Layer, then I can acces The Business Layer, and the Data Layer
>   directly, I do not know if this is correct.
>
> ....
>
> It's acceptable (and accepted), to separate the layers with
>   directories?
>
> It's better (or most accepted) to separate the layers with directories
>   and namespaces, or with projects?

Regarding your first question: it does not matter. Suppose you split each layer into a distinct project (which means you get an assembly for each one). As you noted, you can still access the code in those lower layers from layers up higher. The principles of application layering only says that code in one layer cannot reference code in a higher layer - it does *not* prevent you from accessing code "deeper" in the stack. The only boundary that prevents this is a "tier" boundary - which is far more formal (and more expensive to cross).

Regarding the second question: Sure, you can do this if you wish. It is not mandatory though. You can certainly have a layered architecture without splitting each layer into a subfolder/namespace. Sometimes it might even get in the way. And for some design philosophies (such as some forms of DDD), it is preferred to use namespaces for grouping vertical features while the various classes for each layer all reside within the same feature namespace (often using a class naming convention to identify the layers).

Regarding the third question: I would not separate layers into projects unless you have a good reason to. "Good reasons" would include: sharing code between applications, black-box style unit testing, or preventing dev team conflicts in a large system where dev teams own a portion of the overall system and code needs to merged into the bigger mainline in a very controlled process with formal acceptance checkpoints.

I would certainly not split code into more projects simply for the sake of layering. Each additional project adds overhead to the build process. And at some point, the IDE will start to choke on it (though typically not until you get > 30 or so projects in a solution).

Realistically, the vast majority of mobile apps will not be large or complex enough to justify much thought on this topic. If your project is large enough that you are contemplating splitting it apart along layer boundaries, then it might be time to step back and reconsider the scope.

Answer (score 2):

There is no right answer to this question.  Separation of Concerns is generally considered a good design objective; however, how far you take it and/or exactly how it's implemented will vary from project to project.  For many of the sample projects Xamarin provides, they are not big enough to justify breaking down into separate projects for Data/Domain/etc.

Comment: I supose this ansers the first question It's acceptable to separate the layer in any form, depending on the characteristics of the project. The problem lies in knowing what characteristics has to have the project, to make the separations in one way, or another.

Answer (score 1):

As Jason rightly points out and as with most design decisions, it depends.

Just a few things to think about:

**Splitting by project**

- Clear separation of concerns
- Better code reuse
- Allows for strong naming
- Clearer dependency management (less likely to accidentally reference a project than a namespace)
- Licencing - if you want all developers to work on the model / viewmodel but have only a couple of Xamarin (or other) licenses
- Multiple teams - if the project is big enough, you probably have teams working on each layer.
- With large projects, a split would allow you to each layer to internal repos (e.g. nuget) for other teams to use
- Allows for independent builds / tests of each layer

**Splitting by folder**

- Simpler for smaller applications / POC / prototypes
- Performance - [some discussion here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brada/2004/05/05/perf-trade-off-lots-of-small-assemblies-or-fewer-bigger-assemblies/)
- Less projects, faster IDE and hence faster development
- Less projects, faster build